# Is possible in a Mac App build an iPhone Static Library xcode project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, operating-system

I see that I can build iPhone Static Library xcode project with -xcodebuild into the terminal. So I create a Mac App that execute a shell script which build the project. My question is if I can hide my iPhone Static Library project and its classes from user's eyes.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @Beh, check out the FAQ :) http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0):

your question may need clarification/elaboration.

i *think* you are looking to link your library to an executable (iOS app). once the final executable is linked, invoke the strip command (which can also be configured in Xcode's build settings panel).

Comment: Nope. I try to explain me better =). I'd like to develop a Mac software which make a static library for iPhone projects. My question is that I don't want show to the user objective-c classes that I use to build the static library.

Comment: @Beh there's not much you can do remove exported objc symbols in your binary - assume they must all be exported as declared -- that's just how objc methods/types must be exported. if you want to reduce the number of symbols, consider using a c++ class for your implementation, and then using these c++ objects as private ivars in objc objects (assuming you need objc interfaces). the c++ compiler can inline/remove/strip a ton of information along the way (especially when you avoid virtuals/inheritance). beyond that, there are a ton of ways to make your code unreadable(+to yourself in the process)